# TikTok Login Kit: Status=Temporary Redirect, StatusCode=307

Tags: oauth-2.0, tiktok

I am trying to implement the new TikTok Login Kit for Web and am stuck on the getting the access token.
Here's this specific step described in TikTok's doc.
https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/manage-user-access-tokens

1. I have registered the app.
2. I am able to reach the OAuth login screens.
3. I'm also able auth. and get a response from the auth. endpoint with an authorization code.
4. But when fetching the access token using the said authorization code my POST request comes back to my redirect URL with a "Status=Temporary Redirect, StatusCode=307" in the response.

I assume 307 means there's something missing on the tiktok server, but their support isn't very responsive unfortunately.
Perhaps someone in the community has dealt with this before?

I'm sending my POST request with the following parameters.

```
URL: https://open-api.tiktok.com/oauth/access_token
?code=atGaIopCm2M9L2vfad0l4IJzzX8qFfg7aButDrjqerJqs5rhIqmWZLLGk1YRJZUZ6-mGBaYxX_asSdw1TNe7NHhvysS99Yz5o4MtkNv2-nA*1
&client_key= <client key in plain text>
&client_secret=<secret in plain text>
&grant_type=authorization_code
```

Any ideas what could that 307 Error be hinting at in general?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: not yet, we put it on hold for now, but will revisit it after the holidays, but please let me know if you manage to solve it earlier.

Comment: I was missing a "Location" attribute in the error response body that held the redirect link.

Answer (score 0):

Add -L in your curl command to enable redirections automatically

```
curl -X -L POST  -H 'Content-Type:application/json' --data '{"secret": "xxx","app_id":"xxx","auth_code":"xxx" }' "https://business-api.tiktok.com/open_api/v1.2/oauth2/access_token/"
```

See the document here:
https://ads.tiktok.com/marketing_api/docs?id=1709207085043713